# Interstitial Fails in Horizontal/Landscape

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, iad, interstitial

Hello Stackoverflow users once again, I am returning with another problem with my code. So Im using the iAd framework and trying to implement interstitial ads (once again) It works perfectly fine in portrait however when I swap it into horizontal it returns the following error.

```
"The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable"
```

I am coding in Objective-C and Spritekit. Code can be supplied if necessary! :)

Kind Regards

Ryan

Comment: Which device are you testing on?

Comment: Iphone 6 Plus, iOS 8.3?

Comment: Not really. I told you how to get it work. You haven't implemented it correctly, and you're still relying on the old method of requesting a view. If you do it correctly, the view controller does everything for you and you won't have errors to log. Watch this video https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-222/ and good luck.